# Office365 Email Account Missing from Outlook 2013 Running Windows 7 Pro x64 Roaming Profile Upon Restart

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

I'm currently experiencing this issue whereby upon every restart of the Windows OS, the added office365 account (corporate) will be missing from Outlook 2013 SP1. This only happens to User login in using windows Roaming Profiles. Anyone encountered this before, and have found a way to solve it?

Details:

1) Roaming Profile user login to windows, 
2) Start Outlook, go to File -> Add New Account,
3) Enter email address and credential,
4) Successfully created the account, 
5) Restart Outlook 2013, email added still listed. Emails begin to sync,
6) After completion, restart Windows OS,
7) Upon re-login and start Outlook, email added earlier is missing from the account settings

Thank you.

Comment: Have you spoken to your IT about it ?

Comment: I'm the IT guy....:P

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if you have any defined folders excluded from roaming. Also check if changing from mandatory to local fixes the problem (I know this is commonly unwanted as profile 'cruft" build up), but that should keep permanent profile on the machine.

Check the details of working user and the contents of the :\%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\" directory and compare to that of a non-working users, my hunch is your problem lies in here and it's a sub-directory that is not roaming with users.